# React Native: Style UserLocation in react-native-maps

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

How to style the ‍`UserLocation` on React Native Maps

```
<MapView
    region={this.props.coordinate}
    showsUserLocation={true} // <- style for this option
  >
    //My map markers
</MapView>
```

Style such as

```
{
   position:"absolute",
   top:100,
   right:100,
}
```

Comment: what you tried and what is not working?

Comment: I am also interested in how you can do this. I guess you have to create your own User Location marker to be able to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not directly styling mapView component. All you can do is place mapView inside a normal View and you can styling the View as much as you want.

You can place the style at your separated .js file, i guess with "style" suffix in its filename.